# Smart pointers' "Exception Safety"... Example?

Tags: c++, exception, smart-pointers

What would be a simple illustrative example demonstrating "Exception Safety" feature of C++ smart pointers, always referred in comparisons with raw pointers.

I wouldn't copy the text from the materials, but as I understood, smart pointers should be able to handle case as below, properly releasing the resources for `std::vector`. However, for this code, neither `~A()` nor `~vector()` are ever called - it just throws and fails with out-of-range exception - exactly what is expected from regular pointer. What am I missing?

```
class Aimpl
{
public:
    std::vector<double> x;
};

class A
{
public:
    A() : pimpl(std::make_unique<Aimpl>())
    {
        pimpl->x.resize( 1 );
    };

    ~A()
    {};

    void doMess()
    {
        //out-of-range exception
        pimpl->x[2] = 0;
    };

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Aimpl> pimpl;
};
```

Comment: `operator[]` does not do bounds checking.

Comment: How do you know the destructors aren't being called? How do you know they haven't simply been elided by the compiler? `pimpl->x[2] = 0;` is undefined behavior so it's a moot point regardless.

Comment: [Here](http://ootips.org/yonat/4dev/smart-pointers.html#WhyExceptions)'s a simple example.

Comment: *Why* would any of the destructors be called, even if an exception is thrown? There's nothing you show that would cause the destruction of any object, since there *aren't* any objects. Maybe you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?